# How to add image on basic page content DRUPAL

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm trying to add an image in the content of an article, but I don't know where to point the src....

```
<div class="galeria-servicios"><ul><li><p><img src="../images/albanyileria.jpg" /></p><p>Descripción imagen 1</p></li></ul></div>
```

Comment: I solved it with PHP code:  
<?php print base_path().path_to_theme()?>/images/albanyileria.jpg"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
<img src="/images/albanyileria.jpg" />
```

It should work in case `images` is a folder in the root directory.

Comment: So you mean, if my images folder is at themes/mytheme/images... it should be themes/mytheme/images/image.jpg. Is it a root path then?

Comment: Yup. It's so because when you request any page (for example, a node) you actually request an index.php file with some GET parameters. And as long as index.php is in the root directory, the started point for all the URLs in HTML also should be a root directory. So your src should be `"/themes/mytheme/images/image.jpg"`

Answer (score 1):

By default drupal allows you to use Filtered HTML which among many other things strips out the  tag.

There are a number of approaches to doing it. One would involve you specifying an absolute url  to the image. The second would involve you creating a field for the image and adding it there and then theme the display to suit your needs(works best if it is one image or just a few.)

The third approach would involve using the Image Insert module together with a WYSIWYG editor to insert the images into the article.
Finally, if you feel confident enough with php you can print the image there.(this is not a preferred way of doing things)

My take consider the WYSIWYG editor and Image Insert module. They are well documented on the drupal site.